# Error al generar APK Signed (ProGuard)

Tags: android, android-studio

al generar la APK firmada me informa el siguiente **error** en Messages y no me genera la APK. Pero **si no está firmada funciona sin problemas**:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDevRelease'. > Job failed, see logs for details
```

En el **log** lo único sospechoso que aparece es lo siguiente:

```
INFO - agnostic.FrequentEventDetector - Too many events posted, #1. Event: java.awt.event.ComponentEvent[COMPONENT_RESIZED (-140,-18 1780x100)] on com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.messages.MessageTreeRenderer[,-140,-18,1780x100,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.FrequentEventDetector.eventHappened(FrequentEventDetector.java:74)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.postEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:1085)
    at java.awt.Component.notifyNewBounds(Component.java:2360)
    at java.awt.Component.reshape(Component.java:2316)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.reshape(JComponent.java:4207)
    at java.awt.Component.setBounds(Component.java:2261)
    at java.awt.Component.resize(Component.java:2184)
    at java.awt.Component.setSize(Component.java:2173)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:366)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$NodeDimensionsHandler.getNodeDimensions(BasicTreeUI.java:2807)
    at javax.swing.tree.AbstractLayoutCache.getNodeDimensions(AbstractLayoutCache.java:492)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.updatePreferredSize(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:1360)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.updateNodeSizes(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:918)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.invalidateSizes(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:372)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.redoTheLayout(BasicTreeUI.java:1085)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.access$1200(BasicTreeUI.java:59)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.propertyChange(BasicTreeUI.java:3411)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setCellRenderer(JTree.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer.resetHeightCache(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:453)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer.access$200(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:41)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer$3.resetCaches(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:413)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer$3.reshape(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:409)
    at java.awt.Component.setBounds(Component.java:2261)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.layoutContainer(BorderLayout.java:838)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1510)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1499)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1695)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1704)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1630)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowsPane$AddDockedComponentCmd.run(ToolWindowsPane.java:762)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2017-07-25 22:50:18,493 [7115208]   INFO - agnostic.FrequentEventDetector - Too many events posted, #2. Event: java.awt.event.ComponentEvent[COMPONENT_RESIZED (0,0 1780x100)] on com.intellij.ide.errorTreeView.NewErrorTreeRenderer[,0,0,1780x100,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.FrequentEventDetector.eventHappened(FrequentEventDetector.java:74)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.postEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:1085)
    at java.awt.Component.notifyNewBounds(Component.java:2360)
    at java.awt.Component.reshape(Component.java:2316)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.reshape(JComponent.java:4207)
    at java.awt.Component.setBounds(Component.java:2261)
    at java.awt.Component.resize(Component.java:2184)
    at java.awt.Component.setSize(Component.java:2173)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:366)
    at com.intellij.ide.errorTreeView.NewErrorTreeRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(NewErrorTreeRenderer.java:74)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$NodeDimensionsHandler.getNodeDimensions(BasicTreeUI.java:2807)
    at javax.swing.tree.AbstractLayoutCache.getNodeDimensions(AbstractLayoutCache.java:492)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.updatePreferredSize(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:1360)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.updateNodeSizes(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:918)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.invalidateSizes(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:372)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.redoTheLayout(BasicTreeUI.java:1085)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.access$1200(BasicTreeUI.java:59)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.propertyChange(BasicTreeUI.java:3411)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8428)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setCellRenderer(JTree.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer.resetHeightCache(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:452)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer.access$200(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:41)
    at com.intellij.ui.MultilineTreeCellRenderer$4.componentResized(MultilineTreeCellRenderer.java:435)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6359)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Mi archivo **gradle** contiene el código siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXX.YYYY"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //multiDexKeepProguard 'multidex-config.pro'


        }
    }
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/apache-config-0.4.7-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.httpcore-sources.jar')


    /// GOOGLE ///
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'

    // FIREBASE //
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.0"
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.0'

    /// OTRAS ///
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.github.badoualy:stepper-indicator:1.0.3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:+'
    compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.antonygolovin:fluentsnackbar:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:+'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:+'
    compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:+'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.7.2'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.ceryle:RadioRealButton:v2.0.9'

    /// INSERVIBLES ///
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

¿A qué se debe este error tan poco descriptivo? ¿Algo sobre Pro Guard o Multi Dex?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En verdad necesitas `cruncherEnabled = false` ?, elimina esta parte:

```
  aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }
```

elimina los folders `/build` y su contenido dentro de tu proyecto y vuelve a firmar tu .apk

Comment: Haciendo esto, continúo con el mismo error...